# wilcox.test between multiple grouping variables in r

Tags: r, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have a data set with one numerical variable and 78 binary variables. I know how to perform multiple `wilcox.tests` between multiple numerical variables against one grouping variable (shown [HERE](https://rpubs.com/kaz_yos/1204))

But is it possible to perform a `wilcox.test` between one numerical variable against multiple grouping (binary) variables at the same time, in one step?

Comment: It might be that what you asking for is the Kruskal-Wallis test.

Comment: no, they are 70 differents variables, each has 2 levels